# Set path dynamic for Flink Checkpoint for Flink Job in Yarn Cluser

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am using Yarn for running Flink jobs. For each Flink job I am creating a checkpoint.

I submit a Flink job that runs in my Yarn cluster. I have a polling job which checks if a job has failed on Yarn and restarts it. When the job is submitted again Yarn creates a new application_id for this Flink job.  How can I configure the re-submitted Flink job to use the checkpoint for the Flink job that was restarted.

I have set the conf
     `state.savepoints.dir = hdfs://localhost:9000/checkpoint/` in flink-conf.yaml`

When creating the Flink job, 
`streamExecutionEnvironment.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("hdfs://localhost:9000/checkpoint/uuid-job-1"));`

When I made this setting the checkpoint is saved in path specified in conf file (`hdfs://localhost:9000/checkpoint/`) and not in the path I set when creating the Flink job.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot start a new job with checkpoints from old one. What you can do is to use [externalized checkpoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/state/checkpoints.html#externalized-checkpoints). One drawback in flink <=1.5 is that metadata for externalized checkpoints is stored in a single directory for all jobs which is set by the config parameter: `state.checkpoints.dir`. But you can alter it before each submission.

One additional note from mailing-list [thread](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Retrieving-name-of-last-external-checkpoint-directory-td18351.html):

> The good news is that Flink 1.5 will rework how externalized
>   checkpoints work a bit: basically, all checkpoints can now be
>   considered externalized and the metadata will be stored in the root
>   directory of the checkpoint, not in one global directory for all jobs.
>   This way, the metadata for externalized checkpoints resides in the
>   checkpoint directory of each job and it should be reasonably simple to
>   restore from that.

Comment: `But you can alter it before each submission` - You mean to say that I can set a specific location for each job that I submit using Yarn. I tried this. I used a specific location for each job that I submitted. But it didn't work.

Comment: Do you run your job in a per-cluster job? or multiple jobs in a single cluster? You can alter this setting per each cluster. To alter this setting you have to edit `flink-conf.yaml`.

Comment: The Flink job runs in a Yarn container (multiple containers in the container). 

I deploy the job in the Yarn container. For some reasons my Yarn application dies and I restart this job. I want this job to be able to continue from the last checkpoint. Is it possible to specify a unique path for each job so that if a job dies and I re-submit the job in Yarn the Flink job will use its last saved checkpoint.

Comment: As I said, you can do it with externalized checkpoints enabled and you would need to change the setting `state.checkpoints.dir` in `flink-conf.yaml` before each job submission. Unfortunately you cannot change this setting in code.

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz did I read correctly that it is not possible to set `state.checkpoints.dir` programmatically?